# Can Visual studio 2013 run WP7 project

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, compatibility

I had developed one application for WP8 devices(Target OS is WP8) in VS 2013 with WP8.1 SDK.Now I need to give support to WP7 also.Can I use WP7 SDK on VS2013 and develop app for WP7.So, I will create 2 apps for WP7 and WP8 and upload both on store.

What should be better solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered this problem several times, unfortunaly VS13 does not cooperate if you want to work with WP7 projects.

So if you really want WP7 apps, which I would reconsider since the marketshare is relatively small and I'd guess that people who download apps already have newer versions. Don't forget that lot of features may not be suported and you'd have to come up with new solutions..

Anyway, in case you decide to create WP7, dowload VS12 Express for example, create WP7 project and then copy files from your WP8 and see what works and what not.

Answer (score 2):

You can open an existed project of WP7 using VS2013, but can't create new project by it.

When you create a new project in VS2013, it can only be WP8.0 or 8.1.

Comment: Thanks for answer,but I dont have existing WP7 project.I have WP8.1 SDK with VS2013.Can I make use of VS2013.Whats the solution then?

Comment: I think there are no solution if you havn't existed WP7 project.

Comment: you need to install  VS12 so that you can create a WP7 project, go here https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk and download "Windows Phone SDK 7.1"